# Tidier way of assigning Enter Keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function onLoad() {
    eworkData.FieldByName('SearchReference').HTMLfield.onkeydown=function(evt)
    {
        var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
        if( keyCode == 13 )
        {
            eworkData.FieldByName('cmdSearch').HTMLfield.onfocus();
            eworkData.FieldByName('cmdSearch').HTMLfield.onclick();
        }
    };
    eworkData.FieldByName('SearchFirstName').HTMLfield.onkeydown=function(evt)
    {
        var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
        if( keyCode == 13 )
        {
            eworkData.FieldByName('cmdSearch').HTMLfield.onfocus();
            eworkData.FieldByName('cmdSearch').HTMLfield.onclick();
        }
    };
    // more controls
}
```

Is there a tidier way of doing this?  Smaller compact code?  I think in jQuery I could do

```
$("SearchReference, SearchFirstName").onkeydown(function() ....)
```

However, jQuery isn't an option for me :o(

Comment: I don't think you need to check for `evt` since there will always be an event `onkeydown` so you could reduce that part to `var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;` and in jQuery just `var key = e.which`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function onLoad() {
    var fields = ["SearchReference", "SearchFirstName"];
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        eworkData.FieldByName( fields[i] ).HTMLfield.onkeydown=function(evt) {
            var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
            if( keyCode == 13 ) {
                eworkData.FieldByName('cmdSearch').HTMLfield.onfocus();
                eworkData.FieldByName('cmdSearch').HTMLfield.onclick();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: `evt.which` is unnecessary. In a `keydown` event, `keyCode` works in all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var theElement = document.getElementById("YOUR_ELEMENT");
theElement.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case "13":
           //keycode 13 pressed...
           break;
    }
});
```

or jQuery:

```
$("YOUR_ELEMENT").live("keypress", function(e) {
   switch(e.keyCode) {

   }
});
```

Comment: note that IE only knows `addEventListener()` since version 9.0 so this won't work in older versions.

Comment: There are older versions of IE? ...pffft... whatever :P